# Button crashing program in objective c

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

I am trying to create a simple button, textfield, label program in objective c and I am having button problems.

In file `viewController.m`, I have the following code:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

[button setTitle:@"Look up" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(20,108,97,37);
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

and

```
- (IBAction) buttonPressed:(id) sender  {
[_textField resignFirstResponder];
_label.text = textField.text;
}
```

From what I understand, the button is supposed to to take what is in my text box and put it into a label after I click this button. But instead, pressing the button takes me `main.m` on the return line. And it says the program is paused. If I try to use the program again, it just doesn't work. I have cross examined this button snippet with other code online and can't quite figure out why mine is failing.

Comment: The text field works fine. I've implemented the button and the label after, so I am also not sure if it is actually the button implementation or the label crashing the program. All I know is that once I press the button, everything goes haywire.

Comment: Are you using xibs or storyboards at all? What iOS version? I am pretty sure that to get text out of a textfield you need to use `textField.textLabel.text`

Comment: I don't even know what xibs and storyboards are, so I would guess no. I am using iOS SDK 6.0.

Comment: As for the getting the text out of the textfield, I'm not quite sure if I have even got to that part yet. I implemented the button second and it crashed the program before the label object was even in there.

Comment: Just a quick tip:  since `IBAction` is a macro used by Interface Builder to synchronize actions, you actually don't need it (since you aren't using IB).  Since it resolves to void, it doesn't hurt anything, but it is commonly understood that if you do use `IBAction`, that it's essentially wired to some object via IB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed a colon on this line

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

Your button is calling a method that doesn't exist, thats why it is crashing.

should be

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

OR... change the signature of your buttonPressed method from

```
- (IBAction) buttonPressed:(id) sender;
```

to

```
    - (IBAction) buttonPressed;
```

you should have  seen a message in your log, something like

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewController buttonPressed]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```